# Is it possible to make executable file, .exe, from object file in Windows?

Tags: windows, linker, object-files

I was accessing one of my old codes but the .cpp is not available. Only the .o is available. Other answers on Stackoverflow seem to only be for Linux terminal. Is it possible on Windows by any means?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Have a look at the [ask] link and try to add more 
additional information. Add for example an minimal example.

Comment: Aren't object files named .obj on Windows? Anyway, I'd imagine you do it the same way as on Linux: You run the linker.